# regex: match any word with numbers

Tags: regex

I checked on stackoverflow already but didn't find a solution I could use.
I need a regular expression to match any word (by word I mean anything between full spaces) that contains numbers. It can be alphanumeric **AB12354KFJKL**, or dates **11/01/2014**, or numbers with hyphens in the middle, **123-489-568**, or just plain normal numbers **123456789** - but it **can't** match anything without numbers.
Thanks,

Better example of what I want (in bold) in a sample text:

**ABC1** ABC **23-4787** ABCD **4578** ABCD **11/01/2014** ABREKF

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There must be something better, but I think this should work:

```
\S*\d+\S*
```

`\S*` - Zero or more non-whitespace characters

`\d+` - One or more digits

`\S*` - Zero or more non-whitespace characters

Comment: thanks, but the problem with this regex is that it selects everything, including the spaces, the words without numbers, which i don't want..

Comment: Is there a specific character set you do or do not want?

Comment: Try now: I've changed from `.` to `\S` to capture only non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this lookahead:

```
(?=\D*\d)
```

This asserts that the string contains any quantity of non numeric characters (`\D`) followed by a single digit.

If you want to match/capture the string, then just add `.*` to the regex:

```
(?=\D*\d).*
```

Reference: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: I understand your logic but this is a lookahead without anything to capture any character?